# If every $H$-free $2$-connected graph is Hamiltonian then $H$ is $P_3$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity, hamiltonicity, forbidden-subgraphs

I'm stuck with exercise 5 page 72 of Harris, Hirst and Mossinghoff's *Combinatorics and Graph Theory*:

> 5. Show that if being $H$-free implies Hamiltonicity in $2$-connected graphs (where $H$ is connected), then $H$ is $P_3$.

A $P_3$-free $2$-connected graph is indeed Hamiltonian because $P_3$-free graphs are disjoint unions of cliques, thus a $P_3$-free connected graph is complete, hence Hamiltonian.

What I'm unable to show, however, is that $P_3$ is the unique graph with such a property concerning $2$-connected graphs.

**Attempt**

I tried to solve the problem using contraposition.

Let $H$ be a connected graph that is not isomorphic to $P_3$ and let $n$ be its order.

Let's show that we can find a $2$-connected graph of order $\ge 3$ that are not Hamiltonian yet are $H$-free.

If $n=1$ then $H$ is $K_1$. No graph is $K_1$-free, so we're done with this case.

If $n=2$, since $H$ is connected, $H$ must be $K_2$. No connected graph of order $\ge 2$ is $K_2$-free, so we're done with this case.

If $n=$3, since $H$ is connected and $H\not\cong P_3$, $H$ must be $K_3$. Consider the following graph $G$:[image]

By inspection, the graph is $K_3$-free. The graph is also $2$-connected as it has no cut vertex. Yet the graph is not Hamiltonian. Indeed, let $S={0,2}$ (subset of vertices of $G$). $G-S$ has $3$ connected components, yet $|S|=2<3$, hence the graph is not Hamiltonian according to exercise 10. (a) page 67:

> 10. Let $G$ be a graph and let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $V(G)$.
>
> (a) Prove that if $G$ is Hamiltonian, then $G-S$ has at most $|S|$ connected components

Hence the problem is solved for $H$ of order $\le 3$. But I don't see how I can keep going on to prove the result for all the other connected graphs $H$ of order $\ge 4$. Could you please help me?

**Edit:** As bof showed in the comments, the conclusion of the exercise should be "$H$ is a subgraph of $P_3$".

Comment: Your new tag "hamiltonicity" will be mixed with "Hamiltonian" used in Classical mechanics/symplectic geometry. Might change it to (e.g.) "Hamiltonian-graphs". More importantly, is it necessary to have a new tag on this property?

Comment: The same question goes for "forbidden-subgraphs": is it really necessary?

Comment: @JohnMa You're right "Hamiltonian-graphs" sounds better. I created these tags because they're what the exercise turns around, and I didn't find an existing tag, and I guess that some other questions might be mainly concerned about Hamiltonian graphs or forbidden subgraphs. Is it **really** necessary? I don't know.

Comment: @JohnMa Btw I don't know how to change the name of a tag xD

Comment: You have solved your problem for all $n\le3$ and also for all $n\ge9,$ right? The same example (your graph $G$ of order $8$) works for every graph $H$ which is not an induced subgraph of $G$.

Comment: Pedantically speaking, doesn't the fact that "no graph is $K_1$-free" mean that every $K_1$-free $2$-connected graph ***is*** Hamiltonian? Likewise, isn't it "vacuously" true that every $K_2$-free $2$-connected graph is Hamiltonian? To put it another way, since $K_2$-free implies $P_3$-free, from the fact that every $P_3$-free connected graph is Hamiltonian, it ***follows*** that every $K_2$-free connected graph is Hamiltonian. In short, it seems that the exercise is not stated accurately; the conclusion should be "$H$ is a subgraph of $P_3$" instead of "$H$ is $P_3.$"

Comment: By the way isn't $G=K_{2,3}$ a simpler example for $H=K_3$?

Comment: Looks like $G=K_{2,3}$ works for everything except $H=C_4$ and $H=K_{1,3}.$ You're almost done! You just need two more examples, or maybe one good one.

Comment: @bof Thank you very much for your comments. I didn't notice at all that it also solves the problem for $n\ge 9$, so as you said one just needs to look for other examples. I'm also glad that you shared with me a simpler example for $H=K_3$. I should learn to make use of the $K_{m,n}$ that are Hamiltonian iff $m=n\ge 2$ as a family of examples. Your remark that the conclusion should be "$H$ is a subgraph of $P_3$ is also important. I'm going to send your remark for the authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G_1=K_{2,3}.$

Let $G_2$ be the graph with $9$ vertices and $12$ edges which you get by taking [the graph $Y_3,$ the skeleton of a triangular prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_graph), and subdividing each edge that is not in a triangle.

The graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are $2$-connected and non-Hamiltonian. Therefore, if $H$ is any graph with the property that every $2$-connected graph with no induced subgraph isomorphic to $H$ is Hamiltonian, then $H$ must be isomorphic to an induced subgraph of $G_1$ and of $G_2.$ The only connected graphs occurring as induced subgraphs of both $G_1$ and $G_2$ are $P_1,$ $P_2,$ and $P_3.$

Comment: What a sublime answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!